# PHP readfile() invalid zip

Tags: php, zip

I have a script that looks up a file in a mysql database, sends out some headers, names the file something human-readable, and then delivers it the the user.

It was working for about six months (for thousands of users), until about 6 hours ago.
Now, Windows 7 users now get an error that says "Windows can not open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder: '...filename.zip' is invalid." This happens regardless of browser used to download. Linux users, etc., can open the delivered files just fine, and so can Win7 users if they have, say, WinRAR. Only Windows Explorer can't open them.

**Here's where it gets really weird...** if I make a new copy of my script and remove the various includes that look up the files and decide what to name it, it will download and open just fine... the resulting files from both scripts are identically sized and the resulting name is identical. [Hardcoding the new name into the original script does not help. I kind of thought it might be an encoding issue in the name.] I have tried with a few different zip files with different contents created on different machines by different methods.

The script checks for headers_sent(), file_exists(), and is_readable().

`apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');` was added to the scripts (with no effect) following the only semi-relevant info I could find here or elsewhere on the internet.

Clearly, something in the includes is breaking things somehow, but I haven't any idea what to look for... Ideas? (There are about 300 lines of code in the includes... basically, it's an abstract class for database access, a concrete version of that class for the files and all of their cms info, associated images for the site, etc.)

**On a whim, I added "`ob_clean();` right before the `readfile($file);`... it fixed it. So my question now, is: why? Error reporting is off in all of the files. What else could send output but not headers? And why the "sudden" change in behaivor?**

Comment: You had some output in one of included files. May be even newline or space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Major Issue**

Have seen this error before and took me time to identify the issues because  sometimes its says Header already sent and sometimes it does not.

Here is what i found out :

`ob_clean` works when you discards the contents of the output buffer but if you use `ob_ get_ contents` before calling `ob_clean` you would would see the content causing the error

To output this information make sure you use `var_dump`

**Some other errors**

If there is  a `space (" " or " \n" or "\t")` after calling the `?>` tag i often get errors that can only be resolved by `ob_clean`

Open your script look for script that has more lines of empty space after the `?>` close tag

**Conclusion**

I think there is an empty space included in your script you are not seeing and when you copy it .. you are not copying the script but not the spaces that is why it works elsewhere

Comment: Indeed. There is an extra line break in the beginning of the invalid files. All of the included files have an extra line break after the ?> close tag... I'll fix my IDE's new php file template.

Comment: Am glad i was able to help :D .. Try using Zend Studio or Latest Netbeans .. you would easily see this error

Answer (score 1):

Take out the ob_clean(); and open a damaged file in Wordpad or some hex viewer. The slightest traces of non-binary output (that includes spaces, commas, E_NOTICEs, periods, dust, bird poop etc) will cripple the ZIP.

At best you'll probably just find some E_NOTICES (Warning: undefined constant x assumed 'x' etc.); If not, the hosting probably upgraded/changed something.

The next suspect would be that thing which's name eludes me right now. It's when you have `http://url.com/download.php?file=xxx` Apache sees `.php` and sends `text/php` header. I don't remember what that was called but you fix it with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Yep, there is an extra line break at the beginning of the broken files.

Answer (score 0):

Like Baba said, no spaces (" " or " \n" or "\t") and I suggest to save the php file in UTF8 **without BOM**.